# Uploading images via http post while preserving EXIF data in Android

Tags: android

I am brand new to Android development, and have run into an issue with my first major app that I would very much appreciate help on. The goal of this app is to allow the user to select an image stored on the phone, and upload that image to a server via a http post method, taking the JPEG binary data as a parameter. The catch is that I need to preserve the EXIF data on this as well. I currently have pushed an image onto my emulator's sdcard, and used a basic app to confirm that it is there with the EXIF data.

Here is what I've got so far:

To provide the user with a choice of images, and as a result obtain the image Uri, I use:

`startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI), SELECT_IMAGE);`

In my activity result code, I obtain my Uri with:

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
```

I use this to get a bitmap of the image and display it to the user as a preview.

Here is where I get stuck, as I'm not sue how best to upload it. I have looked a lot at [this example](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/) in hopes of doing something similar, but he seems to be just compressing a bitmap and sending it, which would probably destroy the EXIF data I need, plus I can't even seem to get that to work.

This is the code I'm trying right now, which given my low experience with such things may be entirely wrong:

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
InputStream imageInputStream=this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
String str=imageInputStream.toString();
byte[] imageBits=str.getBytes();
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("where I am sending it");
ByteArrayBody toUpload = new ByteArrayBody(imageBits, "androidpic.jpg");

MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
reqEntity.addPart("userImage", toUpload);
reqEntity.addPart("FileName", new StringBody("android pic"));
post.setEntity(reqEntity);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

This of course does not seem to work.

Does anyone have experience uploading jpegs from the phone like this who could give me some pointers? Any help would be greatly appreciated.